# Python only printing in debug mode

Tags: python, arrays, queue

print only works if i put a breakpoint in print(filaOverbooking) and check the variable details: it shows {...} and if i click somewhere else and check it again, the content shows, after that, i just press continue and the code works, otherwise just print empty:

main:

```
from linkedlist import LinkedList
from queuePas import Queue
from passageiro import Passageiro

listaPassageiros = LinkedList()
filaOverbooking = Queue()
def gerarPassageiro(qtdPassageiros, statusPass):
    for x in range(1,(qtdPassageiros + 1)):
        listaNomes = ['Miguel', 'Arthur', 'Theo', 'Heitor', 'Gael', 'Davi', 'Bernardo', 'Gabriel', 'Ravi', 'Noah', 'Samuel','Pedro', 'Benicio','Benjamin','Matheus', 'Isaac','Anthony' , 'Joaquim', 'Lucas','Lorenzo' , 'Rafael', 'Nicolas', 'Henrique', 'Murilo', 'Miguel', 'Lucca', 'Guilherme', 'Henry', 'Bryan', 'Gustavo', 'Felipe', 'Pietro', 'Levi', 'Daniel', 'Bento', 'Vicente', 'Leonardo', 'Caleb', 'Pedro', 'Matteo', 'Gabriel', 'Joao', 'Antonio', 'Emanuel', 'Enzo', 'Davi', 'Caio', 'Eduardo', 'Lucas']
        
listaSobrenomes = ['Silva', 'Santos', 'das Dores', 'Pinto', 'Coelho', 'Oliveira', 'Souza', 'Alves', 'Lima', 'Pereira', 'Burgarelli', 'de Jesus', 'dos Reis', 'Gomes', 'Costa', 'Martins', 'Ribeiro', 'Almeida', 'Carvalho', 'Lopes', 'Fernandes']
        
listaRuas = ['Rua 10 de Abril', 'Rua Adelina Dossi Becevelli', 'Avenida Adolfo Correia da Silva', 'Travessa Advalter Braganca', 'Rua Afonso Claudio', 'Rua Alexandre Vargas', 'Beco Alexandrino Coelho Araujo', 'Rua Alfredo Pereira de Chagas', 'Rua Alice Laranja', 'Rua Alice Nunes Kull', 'Rua Algas Marinhas', 'Avenida Esperanca', 'Rua Ana Pestana']
        listaCidades = ['Colatina', 'Vitoria', 'Vilha-Velha', 'Linhares', 'Serra', 'Guarapari', 'Afonso Pena']

        cpf = str(random.randint(10000000000, 11000000000))
        rg = str(random.randint(1000000, 1100000))
        celular = str(random.randint(990000000, 999999999))
        telefone = str(random.randint(10000000, 20000000))
        numero = str(random.randrange(1,3000))
        endereco = ''.join(listaRuas[random.randint(0, (len(listaRuas) - 1))]) + ", " + numero + ", " + ''.join(listaCidades[random.randint(0, (len(listaCidades) - 1))]) + ", ES"
        assento = str(x)
        if statusPass == "Overbooking":
            passageiro = Passageiro(''.join(listaNomes[random.randint(0, (len(listaNomes) - 1))]), ''.join(listaSobrenomes[random.randint(0, (len(listaSobrenomes) - 1))]), cpf, rg, endereco, celular, telefone)
            filaOverbooking.push(passageiro)
        elif statusPass == "Confirmado":
            passageiro = Passageiro(''.join(listaNomes[random.randint(0, (len(listaNomes) - 1))]), ''.join(listaSobrenomes[random.randint(0, (len(listaSobrenomes) - 1))]), cpf, rg, endereco, celular, telefone, statusPass, assento)
            listaPassageiros.addNode(passageiro)


gerarPassageiro(10, "Overbooking")

print(filaOverbooking)
```

---

```
class Passageiro:
    
    def __init__(self, nome, sobrenome, cpf, rg, endereco, telCelular, telFixo, statusVoo="Overbooking", assento="-"):
        self.nome = nome
        self.sobrenome = sobrenome
        self.cpf = cpf
        self.rg = rg
        self.endereco = endereco
        self.telCelular = telCelular
        self.telFixo = telFixo
        self.statusVoo = statusVoo
        self.assento = assento

    def __repr__(self):
        data = ' '
        data = "Nome: " + self.nome + '\n'
        data = data + "Sobrenome: " + self.sobrenome + '\n'
        data = data + "cpf: " + self.cpf + '\n'
        data = data + "rg: " + self.rg + '\n'
        data = data + "endereco: " + self.endereco + '\n'
        data = data + "Celular: " + self.telCelular + '\n'
        data = data + "Telefone: " + self.telFixo + '\n'
        data = data + "Status do Voo: " + self.statusVoo + '\n'
        data = data + "Assento: " + self.assento + '\n'
        data = data + "--------------------------------------\n"
        
        return data
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()
```

---

```
from queuenode import QueueNode


class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self._size = 0
        self.maxSize = 10
        self.queueIterator = self.first

    def push(self, elem):
        # insere um elemento na lista

        if self._size < self.maxSize:
            node = QueueNode(elem)

            if self.first is None and self.last is None:
                self.first = node
                self.last = node

            else:
                self.last.next = node
                self.last = node

            self._size += 1

        else:
            raise IndexError("Can't add. The queue is full")

    def pop(self):
        # remove um elemento da lista

        if self._size > 0:
            elem = self.first.data
            self.first = self.first.next
            self._size -= 1
            return (elem + "removed from queue")

        raise IndexError("Can't remove. The queue is empty")

    def peek(self):
        # retorna o topo da lista
        if self._size > 0:
            return self.first.data

        raise IndexError("The queue is empty")

    def __len__(self):
        # retorna o tamanho da lista
        return self._size

    def nextNode(self):
        self.queueIterator = self.queueIterator.next
        if not self.queueIterator:
            self.queueIterator = None

    def __repr__(self):
        fila = ""
        posicao = 1
        while (self.queueIterator):
            fila = fila + str(posicao) + ": " + str(self.queueIterator.data)
            self.nextNode()
            posicao += 1
        fila = fila.strip(", ")
        self.queueIterator = self.first
        return fila
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()
```

ouput using checkpoint(just a sample):

### 1: Nome: Matheus
Sobrenome: Carvalho
cpf: 10947455233
rg: 1082637
endereco: Rua Alice Nunes Kull, 147, Vitoria, ES
Celular: 995282420
Telefone: 17498892
Status do Voo: Overbooking
Assento: -

### 2: Nome: Anthony
Sobrenome: Lopes
cpf: 10314633731
rg: 1028954
endereco: Rua 10 de Abril, 2747, Colatina, ES
Celular: 994457278
Telefone: 12448801
Status do Voo: Overbooking
Assento: -

[before i click somewhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kctC.png)

[after i click somewhere and click on it again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHOUX.png)

Comment: You appear to have written a mutative `__repr__`. `__repr__` should never do that.

Comment: _and if i click somewhere else and check it again_ Sounds like you're using an IDE or a debugger.  Please give those details.

Comment: Im using Visual Studio. Seems like if i dont do the breakpoint and all that thing with mouse, it just skips the while loop inside Queue __repr__  even  self.queueIterator being true, and returns fila =""

Comment: added images to clarify